# How convert NodeJS files to Vanilla files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a module in NodeJs, the entry main is main.js:

```
main.js
└─┬ source
  ├── a.js
  ├── b.js
  ├── c.js
  └── d.js
```

This module has module.export in the main file like

```
module.exports = ZTree;
```

And have a requires in each file. I don't use requires of node modules or other modules. Only files in **source** folder.

So, I want to use this module in a web application, in a single js file. So I tried with webpack:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './ztree/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'rtree'),
        filename: 'ztree.js'
    },
}
```

But when I set in my test.html the script:

```
 <script src="./ztree.js"></script>
```

I can't use it.

So, my question is how I can convert "NodeJS files" to "Vanilla files" for web.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use it? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: @Matt if is pure I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
" and if I use webpack I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Ztree is not defined"

Comment: Have you tried using this option? https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library

Comment: You are crack! Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@justin-summerlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255127/how-convert-nodejs-files-to-vanilla-files#comment81461233_47255127) for solve the answer.

Must add **libraryTarget** and **library** in the output on **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './ztree/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'rtree'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: 'ZTree'
    },
}
```

And in your HTML file you can use it like:

```
let ztree = new ZTree(); // As your library name
```